# MX and CNAME records not updating

Tags: domain-name-system, mx-record, cname-record

I have transferred a domain from GoDaddy to Google Domains. About 12 hours ago I changed the name servers to point to Google Domains name servers. [image: Name server settings]

At the same time I added the following MX and CNAME records. [image: MX and CNAME records]

When I run a DNS lookup from ultratools.com I see the name servers are showing up, but the MX and CNAME records are not. [image: DNS Lookup Result]

Is there an issue with the way I entered the records, or do I just need to wait a bit longer for the records to be updated?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

subdomain must be specifically queried, and your mx records are wrong, the names should be `@` but you have the subdomain of `0` and `10`